# How to hide and show jpgs after submitting mailchimp

Tags: javascript

I'm really a newbie in programming stuff and I've been learning by myself HTML and Javascript looking for information in books, forums and friends this summer.

So I have this project that I'm releasing the 1th October and I'm struggling with trying to hide and show some jpgs.

My purpose is to have at the end of the HTML this Mailchimp subscription box where I say that 'if you subscribe to this Webcomic you will get a look to the first page of the next chapter'. So when somebody submits his email the jpg displays.

This is the mailchimp code.

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//romanbk.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=e398c205a943a35571238434b&amp;id=10e55b870c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL" style="color:white">Subscribe to this Webcomic</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_e398c205a943a35571238434b_10e55b870c" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And these are the jpgs that I'm trying to hide and show. They are already hidden, but how to show them?

```
<div id="Chapter2" class="chapter2" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center; display: none">
    <img src="Pages/Cover.jpg" >
    <img src="Pages/Page2-1.jpg">
</div>
```

I've been trying some Javascript codes that I've found on this forum but none have worked for me or I have not understood at all how they work. Is there any way to do what I want? I'm sure there have to be a code but still hard to achieve. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    $("#Chapter2").show();
});
```

JSBIN demo here: https://jsbin.com/lageqeguju/edit?html,console,output